# Utilize keyof to determine return type automatically

Tags: typescript

I have an interface as follows

```js
interface ResourceState<ItemType> {
rows: ItemType[],
store: Record<String, ItemType>
}
```

And I create a root state as follows

```js
RootState{
car: ResourceState<Car>
user: ResourceState<User>
}
```

I defined a service as a function that accepts the id and returns an instance of the resource (via an API, random generator or something else)

```js
type Service<Resource>=(id: string)=> Promise<Resource>
```

I want to define a mapping which tells the system how to load the resource for any of the items in the `RootState`

```js
export const storeServicesMapping : Record<keyof RootState, Service<???> >={
"user": (id:string)=>Promise.resolve({} as User)//should work
"car": (id:string)=>Promise.resolve({} as User)//should not work, it should expect Service<Car>

}
```

So based on the key from the root state, it should decide the type of the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all possible key/`Service<key>` combinations with a mapped type.

```
type StoreServicesMapping = {
    [K in keyof RootState]: 
      Service<RootState[K] extends ResourceState<infer U> 
        ? U 
        : never
      >
}
```

For each key `K` in `RootState` this will add a property to the resulting type with the key `K` and the corresponding `Service` type. For the `Service` type, you can get the `ItemType` out of the `ResourceState` with `infer`.

```
export const storeServicesMapping : StoreServicesMapping = {
  "user": (id:string)=>Promise.resolve({} as User),
  "car": (id:string)=>Promise.resolve({} as User) // Error: 'Promise<User>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Car>'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=17&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgQwE4wLwwN4wQLhgZxCQEsA7AcxgF9RJYBVfKFdLAIz0JIuuGDJDMAZggDGsAEpR8AewCuScQGUQCQQB4AkoIC2AFToA%20TMBhmYSGQHd8ebVH10A2gF0ANKfOEZSKHimiPgAm6lxk5G4w9o7QhsA0-KSCSCLiMBIyMiAqalAYnmaiyP7S8opQORqISHHmMHJMSCWyCsqqGozMcQng0DBKzABuxOLqUi3lhqgAFMRBnEThAJSoxgAKljrETGOlrVBxtH0qPhVDI9IAsggQEOFoJnVOANIwZDAA1lBgMkLpmdl2lAXHgCuYBkhhqMMllKlAXi4YFAAB6CUhBfDpPblOHqMhCZgwejGMF1AD8RJgpPMeFIUEGzGp3T4KIgPhAMECpEIBBApwhUKuNzuPDwJ18Aou%20Gut3urE8ACIGswFXhZvMwhQVoYNjItkwAHS%20WQAGwZ0wwVGwmM6SCWHjMCqKSFVMHVOE15G1uv1UCNpTNUAtVoQNsaSxgAHpIzAAKJISxNGAAch92yg6lthmTb0xpCy1vwxHIpAQbBNsD5MF6sFTm3T6mq2fiQA)